# Is there any Single sign-on project integrated both twitter and facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, single-sign-on, sharekit

I'm developing an ios app and I want to allow users sign in with Twitter and Facebook. Is there any open source project like [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com) integrated both ? Or is there project integrated into ShareKit?

Answer (score 1):

You now have the twitter framework inside the iOS SDK. So I would advise you sticking with that. The Facebook, on the other hand is still not a part of the iOS SDK. Nevertheless, it's quite simple to integrate it in your application (if you are able to spend 20 minutes by yourself to learn it). You can check it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/).

Comment: Thank you! I have tested this according to the facebook iOS Tutorial.It works well.I'm not sure if it will work with sharekit

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility is to use [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). Original ShareKit is not maintained anymore. [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) uses iOS5 Twitter framework and Facebook SSO. If you decide to use [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit), make sure to follow updated [installation guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit). You can make a quick preview of what ShareKit is capable running the demo app.